# Call either system's Python or virtualenv's Python in a Python script

Tags: python, shell, virtualenv

Suppose you write a Python shell script. It will probably start with something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

The problem is, if you often work with `virtualenv` this call is just plain wrong. You actually would like this script to call virtualenv's python binary, if it is in this environment and `/usr/bin/python/` otherwise. Just like your shell would decide, when you write `python` as a shell command.

How would you write your `#!` line to fulfil this requirement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `#!/usr/bin/env python` instead.

The [`env` command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/env) looks up binaries in the current `PATH`; activating your virtual environment adds your virtualenv `bin/` directory to the path and `env` will find your python binary there instead of the global python.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

...